# emacs crashing in 20.10

Tags: gnome-shell, crash, gtk, emacs

I just upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and now emacs is crashing frequently. This never happened for me in any earlier version of Ubuntu. I started from the shell and at the time of the crash, I see:

```
X protocol error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) on protocol request 25
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/221
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.
```

Why did this problem show up with 20.10. Is there a workaround, such as building emacs using a GUI toolkit other than GTK?

### NEW INFORMATION 2020-11-03:

I now realize that this problem is the result of gnome-shell randomly (presumably crashing and) restarting. Although other apps (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Audacious, terminal) recover from this event, it apparently triggers the "X disconnect" to emacs in the above-quoted error message. This only started happening since upgrading to 20.10, and only on my desktop (System76 Ratel Pro). It is not happening on my laptop (System76 Galego Pro) also running 20.10. The desktop has Intel graphics and is connected to my monitor via HDMI, in case that's relevant.

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening for me, too, on Ubuntu 20.10.  I've rebuilt Emacs 27.1 from source without GTK, too.

Comment: My workaround was to abandon the crashy, unstable, default Gnome UI for StumpWM instead ( http://stumpwm.github.io/ ).  I can confirm that that has fixed the problem :)

Comment: I submitted a Gnome bug report about this problem: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3488
and as can be seen from comments, this is a known problem which has been fixed in gnome-shell 3.38.2 that involves the Desktop Icons extension. Based on this, I have disabled that extension and the crashes have stopped (it has now been almost 48 hours since the last crash). Notice that there are two Ubuntu launchpad bugs referenced in the comments. So I assume there will be a future Ubuntu software update to gnome-shell fixing this bug.